# Continuation of Linear Operator in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

First of all, here is the assignment:

> Let $X$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$, $V \subseteq X$ be a closed subspace and $f \in L(V, \mathbb{C}) $ a linear continuous operator.
>   Show that there exists one unique continuation $F$ of $f$ on $X$, such that all these properties are satisfied:
>
> 1. $F \in L(X, \mathbb{C})$ (i.e., linear and continuous),
> 2. $F|_V = f$,
> 3. $\|F\| = \|f\|$.

There is also a hint given: Use the Riesz representation theorem. Ok, so I should know where to start, but fact is: I have no real clue. I know that using Riesz theorem property 3 can easily be shown from property 2. But how do I prove that there exists this continuation?
I'd be glad if anyone could give me a hint on how to approach this.

Comment: Since $V$ is closed, $V$ endowed with the inner product of $X$ is a Hilbert space. So $f$ and be represented as $f(\cdot)=\langle v_0,\cdot\rangle$. Now use this formula to extend it to $X$ and check that all properties are satisfied.

Comment: It is also true if $V$ is not closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $V$ is a closed subspace of $X$, it is a Hilbert space too. By the Riesz representation theorem $f$ is of the form $f(v) = \langle v, \xi \rangle$ for a unique $\xi \in V$. Now note that $F(x) = \langle x, \xi\rangle$ is defined for all $x \in X$ and satisfies all the requirements. I'll leave uniqueness of the extension $F$ to you.